# Any who has done any smart contract analysis?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs

I want to analyze smart contract application and I wanted to know if there is a crawler for it and after the contracts have been crawled using the data's from the contracts to analyze each block.

Comment: can you be more specific? are you trying to analyse a smart contract or a decentralised application? are you requesting in terms of security/bugs or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is in terms of security. analyzing ethereum transactions to be specific.

Comment: OK, got it. If it's solely smart contract security, perhaps look into https://tool.smartdec.net, you can add multiple contracts and analyse them for potential vulnerabilities. if it is more related to on-chain data exploration look into alethio.io and ethstats perhaps I'm sure you can pull out the necessary data from those for analysis as well.

Answer (score 1):

People often use block explorers like [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io) to explore activity on-chain. If this is not what you are looking for, you might find a website we launched a few months ago interesting. Smart Contract Monitor allows you to view analytics / transaction info focused on smart contracts. Example:

https://smartcontractmonitor.com/main/0x06012c8cf97bead5Deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/overview

*As phant0m mentioned - if you can provide more detail about what you are looking for, someone will likely follow up with a more targeted answer. Good luck!*

Comment: To analyze ethereum transactions in terms of security. crawling many ethereum transactions and analyze those addresses.